# how to sum two matrices element by element?

Tags: assembly, matrix, x86, addressing-mode

I am new to assembly and I would be grateful if you would help me with a piece of code on how to add two matrices and move the result in another matrix, in assembly language x86-32bit. The matrices are declared as 1d arrays.

```
n dd 9
A dd 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
B dd 2,0,4,5,6,7,0,1,3
sum dd dup 9(0)
```

I tried the code below, but it only works for matrices declared like that and I would need one to work for a matrices declared as 1s array.

```
A db 1,2,3
   db 4,5,6
B db 7,8,9
   db 10,11,12
.code
start:
mov eax , 0 
mov esi, 0 
mov ebx, 0 

add al, A[ebx][esi]
add al, B[ebx][esi]
mov A[ebx][esi], al
mov al, 0
inc esi
add al, A[ebx][esi]
add al, B[ebx][esi]
mov A[ebx][esi], al
mov al, 0
inc esi
add al, A[ebx][esi]
add al, B[ebx][esi]
mov A[ebx][esi], al

mov al, 0
mov esi, 0
add ebx, 3 
add al, A[ebx][esi]
add al, B[ebx][esi]
mov A[ebx][esi], al
mov al, 0
inc esi
add al, A[ebx][esi]
add al, B[ebx][esi]
mov A[ebx][esi], al
mov al, 0
inc esi
add al, A[ebx][esi]
add al, B[ebx][esi]
mov A[ebx][esi], al
 push 0
call exit
end start
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matrices that are contiguous in memory (like C 2D arrays) are equivalent to  1D arrays, just `rows * cols` elements in a row in memory, regardless of what asm syntax you use to put them there.  The only thing that makes them a  2D matrix is how you index them, e.g.
`flat_index row * width + col`.

(And for looping over it, you can of course do `row_offset += width`; that's the `add ebx, 3` in your 2x3 byte matrix code.)

**Per-element addition of matrices doesn't have to care about their dimensions at all, it's exactly the same problem as per-element array addition**.  So just loop an index or pointer over each array and add.

Then you don't need 2 separate indices for row vs. column that's just going to make your code more complicated, or (for such small dimensions) almost worth fully unrolling like you did the 2nd time.

(Or if your CPU supports SSE2, you can do it 4 dwords at a time with `paddd`.)

---

**This is not special:**

```
A db 1,2,3
   db 4,5,6
```

Declaring like this, with 2 separate `db` lines for separate rows, is equivalent to one long array.  For MASM, it might change the `SIZEOF A` (you probably only get the first row that's actually on the same line as the `A` label), but nothing else changes.

**The reason the code that goes with it won't work for your case is that it uses byte elements, and has a different matrix size (9 elements instead of 6).**  Nothing to do with how it's declared.

You *could* fully unroll a loop and do a bunch of complicated moving and adding of integer registers if you wanted to, but there's no point.

---

`A[ebx][esi]` isn't valid syntax in most(?) assemblers.  If it assembles, I assume it means
**`A[ebx + esi]`**.  That would be the normal way to write that.

It's not doing matrix indexing for you, that's why you still have to use byte offsets to go to the next row.

You can use stuff like `A[ebx*4 + esi]` if the number of columns is an assemble-time-constant power of 2 (specifically 1, 2, 4, or 8; x86 addressing modes have  2-bit shift count for the index).

Normally in asm syntax you write `[base + index*scale]`, but Intel-syntax assemblers don't actually care which order the components of an addressing mode appear in.  So if you like to think in C, where the left index strides over whole rows to select a column, then writing it as `[A + ebx*4 + esi]` makes sense if you had a `uint8_t [2][4]` matrix, so the stride from an element to the next row down is 4.

For dword element (like in your first example) instead of byte elements (like your 2nd), you'd need to scale your indices or by 4 already (like `A[ebx*4]` or make them byte offsets by using `add esi, 4` instead of `inc esi`.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to sum up any 2 arrays A and B by writing the output on Array C you could supply as 
the input parameter of your function the size of the matrix A, which is equal to that of the matrix B and 
of the matrix C: MAT_SIZE.
To calculate MAT_SIZE you simply need to multiply the number of rows by the number 
of columns (mono and bi dimensional matrices). If the number of indexes is> 2 then 
MAT_SIZE will be the product of all the (maximum indices + 1) (assuming that 0 points to 
the first element and n-1 points to the last).
I suppose the matrices contain cells of 1 Byte.

```
;Indexes Max-Index+1 MAT_Size 
;      3           8    8*8*8

;ROUTINE @@MAT

;INPUT: EAX: First matrix pointer. Unaltered
;       EDX: Second matrix pointer. Unaltered.
;       EBX: Target matrix pointer. Unaltered.
;       ECX: MAT_Size. Unaltered.

@@MAt:PUSH  EBP           ; Save EBP.
      MOV   EBP,EBX       ; Copy EBX into EBP.

      JECXZ @@00          ; If matrix is empty, terminate sub-routine.

      PUSH  ECX           ; Save ECX.

 @@01:Mov   BL,[EAX]      ; Load in BL first byte.
      Add   BL,[EDX]      ; Add to BL second byte.
      MOV   [EBP],BL      ; Save result in [EBP].

      INC   EAX           ; Increase First matrix pointer.
      INC   EDX           ; Increase Second matrix pointer.
      INC   EBP           ; Increase Target matrix pointer.

      LOOP  @@01          ; If target matrix is full, end.

      POP   ECX           ; Resume MAT_SIZE

      SUB   EAX,ECX       ; Adjust First matrix pointer.
      SUB   EDX,ECX       ; Adjust Second matrix pointer.

      MOV   EBX,EBP
      SUB   EBX,ECX       ; Adjust Target matrix pointer.

 @@00:POP   EBP           ; Resume EBP.

      RET                 ; Return from sub-routine.
```

On real x86 mode, supposing the matrix are in data segment you can similar wrote:

```
;Indexes Max-Index+1 MAT_Size 
;      3           8    8*8*8

;ROUTINE @@MT2

;INPUT: SI: First matrix offset. Unaltered
;       DI: Second matrix offset. Unaltered.
;       BX: Target matrix offset. Unaltered.
;       CX: MAT_Size. Unaltered.

@@MT2:PUSH  BP            ; Save BP.
      MOV   BP,BX         ; Copy BX into BP.

      JCXZ  @@00          ; If matrix is empty, terminate sub-routine.

      PUSH  CX            ; Save ECX.

 @@01:Mov   BL,DS:[SI]    ; Load in BL first byte.
      Add   BL,DS:[DI]    ; Add to BL second byte.
      MOV   DS:[BP],BL    ; Save result in [BP].

      INC   SI            ; Increase First matrix offset.
      INC   DI            ; Increase Second matrix offset.
      INC   BP            ; Increase Target matrix offset.

      LOOP  @@01          ; If target matrix is full, end.

      POP   CX            ; Resume MAT_SIZE

      SUB   SI,CX         ; Adjust First matrix offset.
      SUB   DI,CX         ; Adjust Second matrix offset.

      MOV   BX,BP
      SUB   BX,CX         ; Adjust Target matrix pointer.

 @@00:POP   BP            ; Resume BP.

      RET                 ; Return from sub-routine.
```

Comment: I think the reason this didn't get any upvotes is that the real question here is *whether* a 2D matrix looks the same as a 1D array in assembly.  But sure, have an upvote, even though this uses the slow `loop` instruction.  Subtracting the size after the pointer-increment loop is an interesting way to restore the original register values.  (However, using indexed addressing modes would be at least as efficient on all CPUs, and more efficient on most, than 3 separate pointer increments if you don't unroll the loop.)  Still, maybe helpful to have a concrete example for some beginners.

Comment: Thank you very much Mister Peter Cordes ! You are the best for me. God luck.

Comment: Ora devo dormire ancora un pò e chiudo per un pò l' account come mi hanno detto ianche i moderatori.